# Printing ssh log to a list using JSCH (android)

Tags: java, android, listview, ssh, jsch

I've been trying to print the items in my directory in a listView by adding the log.i string values which contains the names of my directory into an array and then using an array adapter to print them via listView. However, when I try to run the app, it prints the log containing the names of my directory, but it doesn't print anything on the listView. Any help?

Here's my code:

```
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
    import java.io.DataOutputStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Properties;

    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;

    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

    import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;

    import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
    import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private String user = "root"; //username
        private String pass = "password"; //password
        private String host = "hostname"; //hostname
        private int portNum = 22; //replace port number

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                    try {
                        executeRemoteCommand(user, pass, host, portNum);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }.execute(1);

        }

        public String executeRemoteCommand(String username, String password, String hostname, int port)
                throws Exception {

            //declare list and array
            final ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.choose_sound_listView);
            ArrayList<String> soundNames = new ArrayList<String>();

            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, port);
            session.setPassword(password);

            // Avoid asking for key confirmation
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(prop);

            session.connect();


            Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
            channel.connect();

            DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(channel.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(channel.getOutputStream());

            // send ls command to the server
            dataOut.writeBytes("ls\r\n");
            dataOut.flush();

            // and print the response
            String line = dataIn.readLine();
            String out = line + "\n";

            // loop to add log string values to array
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                line = dataIn.readLine();
                out += line + "\n";
                Log.i("SSH", ": " + line);
                //add to array
                soundNames.add(line);
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1
                    , soundNames);


            list.setAdapter(adapter);

            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                        int position, long arg3) {

                    // Show Alert
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Alert", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

            dataIn.close();
            dataOut.close();
            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();

            return out;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not set the adapter in a background thread. Also I modified your `executeRemoteCommand` according to [Jsch Exec example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html). These are my modifications:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.choose_sound_listView);

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>>() {
        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                return executeRemoteCommand(user, pass, host, portNum);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(List<String> soundNames){
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, soundNames);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }.execute();
}

public List<String> executeRemoteCommand(String username, String password, String hostname, int port) throws Exception {

    List<String> soundNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, port);
    session.setPassword(password);

    // Avoid asking for key confirmation
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(prop);

    session.connect();

    String command = "ls -la | awk '{ print $9}'";

    Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);

    ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

    InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

    System.out.println("Connect to session...");
    channel.connect();

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    //This is the recommended way to read the output
    byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
    while (true) {
        while (in.available() > 0) {
            int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
            if (i < 0) {
                break;
            }
            buffer.append(new String(tmp, 0, i));
        }
        if (channel.isClosed()) {
            System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
            break;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception ee) {
        }
    }
    channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(buffer.toString());
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        soundNames.add(line);

        Log.i("SSH", ": " + line);
    }

    return soundNames;
}
```